# Delete reverse duplicate rows using sql

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
column1 column2
x       y
y       x
```

how does one go about eliminating such duplicates? or at worst selecting just one of those tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to identify only the valid rows e.g.

```
SELECT column1, column2
  FROM T
 WHERE column1 <= column2
UNION
SELECT column2 AS column1, column1 AS column2
  FROM T
 WHERE column1 > column2;
```

...then delete rows that aren't in the set of valid rows:

```
DELETE 
  FROM T
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM (
                           SELECT column1, column2
                             FROM T
                            WHERE column1 <= column2
                           UNION
                           SELECT column2 AS column1, column1 AS column2
                             FROM T
                            WHERE column1 > column2
                          ) AS DT1
                    WHERE DT1.column1 = T.column1 
                          AND DT1.column2 = T.column2
                  );
```

Alternatively, the `DELETE` may be simplified to target only the invalid rows:

```
DELETE 
  FROM T
 WHERE column1 > column2
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM T AS T1
                    WHERE T1.column1 = T.column2 
                          AND T1.column2 = T.column1
                  );
```

Answer (score 5):

It's become kind of a mainstream habit among question askers to withhold the information which RDBMS we are dealing with. In response: this is tested and works with a certain RDBMS I am not inclined to name. Go figure!

```
DELETE FROM tbl a
USING  tbl b
WHERE  (a.x, a.y) = (b.y, b.x)
AND    a.y > a.x  -- keep the one dupe with the biggest x
```

Assuming there are no dupes with `x = y`. This would be an ordinary duplicate anyway.

Comment: The thing is i don't know which RDBMS they are use either,i'm doing an online course which only mentions that we will be using SQL(which i mentioned in the question itself) thank you for the answer anyway

Comment: @Ashwin: Sorry for the attitude. You just happen to be caught up in something. :) It's so much easier to answer if we know the RDBMS. My solution works in PostgreSQL where you can join in additional tables to a `DELETE` with [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html). Some other RDBMS use other techniques.

Comment: It's become kind of a mainstream habit to use the term "relational" (the 'R' in 'RDBMS') when one means 'SQL'. The Standard SQL specs purposely avoid the use of the word 'relation' and its derivatives.

Comment: ...speaking of Standards, using a correlation name (for which it's become kind of a mainstream habit to use the term "alias") should have the effect of materializing a table which immediately goes out of scope i.e. the base tables would remain unaffected, which is surely not the OP's intention. Therefore, your SQL statement is wrong as regards 'sql'.

Comment: The syntax is for PostgreSQL and the alias is an alias, **not** a correlation. [Consult the fine manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-delete.html). Nothing goes out of scope, my statement is perfectly correct.